# Trying to send data to database with AJAX (CI)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

i have a problem with my AJAX, not posting any data to my database, i have googled the internet dry, and now i ended up here.

I tried in Postman, inserting my Json data (seen below) and i did a POST to my method in my API controller(user/add_user), my controller then runs the query from my model, and it is inserted into the database correctly.

```
{
"first_name": "Admin",
"last_name": "Panna",
"email": "Admin2@mail.com",
"password": "Admin1234",
"phone_number": "12345678",
"address": "Nowhere 1",
"city": "somwhere",
"country": "Germany",
"nationality": "Finnish",
"speak_danish": "1",
"colleague": "Dora The Explorer",
"task": "Security"
}
```

So the problem is really that my frontend, with my jquery ajax calls is not doing a POST, or atleast not right, because i cant see any data being send anywhere, and in the console tool in the browser, in the network tab, no POST method is being listed :(

Here is my function that loads the HTML in my API (just so you can see the HTML code)

```
function registrationPage() {
var html =
    '<div class="register-text container">'
        +'<h3>You are about to register as a volunteer for</h3>'
        +'<img src="' + RESS +'img/tinderbox_date.svg">'
    +'</div>'
    +'<div class="register-input container">'
        +'<div>'
            +'<input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">'
            +'<input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">'
            +'<input id="first_name" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">'
            +'<input id="last_name" type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">'
            +'<select id="gender" name="gender" placeholder="Gender">'
                +'<option value="" disabled selected>Gender</option>'
                +'<option value="1">Female</option>'
                +'<option value="0">Male</option>'
            +'</select>'
            +'<label for="dateofbirth">Date of Birth</label>'
            +'<input id="dateofbirth" placeholder="Date of Birth" type="date" name="dateofbirth" >'
            +'<select id="nationality" name="nationality" >'
                +'<option value="nationality" disabled selected>Nationality</option>'
                +'<option value="Danish">Danish</option>'
                +'<option value="German">German</option>'
                +'<option value="norwegian">Norwegian</option>'
            +'</select>'
            +'<div class="upload-image">'
                +'<img src="images/picture.svg">'
                +'<p>Upload image</p>'
            +'</div>'
            +'<input id="phonenumber" type="number" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Phonenumber">'
            +'<input id="address" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address">'
            +'<select id="country" name="country" placeholder="Country">'
                +'<option value="Denmark">Country</option>'
                +'<option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>'
                +'<option value="germany">Germany</option>'
                +'<option value="Norway">Norway</option>'
            +'</select>'
            +'<input id="zipcode" type="number" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip code">'
            +'<input input="city" type="text" name="city" placeholder="City">'
            +'<select id="speak_danish" name="speak_danish">'
                +'<option value="danish" disabled selected>Speak and understand Danish</option>'
                +'<option value="1">Yes</option>'
                +'<option value="0">No</option>'
            +'</select>'
            +'<select id="task" name="task">'
                +'<option value="tasks" label disabled selected>Preferred work tasks</option>'
                +'<option value="fences">Building Fences</option>'
                +'<option value="bartender">Bartender</option>'
                +'<option value="it-work">IT Work</option>'
            +'</select>'
            +'<input id="colleague" type="text" name="colleague" placeholder="I like to work with (name)">'
            +'<button class="link-register-user" type="submit" value="REGISTER">Register</button>'
        +'</div>'
    +'</div>';

jQuery('#main').html(html);
}
```

and the AJAX i have for it is here

```
function register(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var emailVal = jQuery('#email').val();
var passwordVal = jQuery('#password').val();
var first_nameVal = jQuery('#first_name').val();
var last_nameVal = jQuery('#last_name').val();
var genderVal = jQuery('#gender').val();
var dateofbirthVal = jQuery('#dateofbirth').val();
var phone_numberVal = jQuery('#phone_number').val();
var addressVal = jQuery('#address').val();
var cityVal = jQuery('#zipcode').val();
var zipcodeVal = jQuery('#city').val();
var countryVal = jQuery('#country').val();
var nationalityVal = jQuery('#nationality').val();
var speak_danishVal = jQuery('#speak_danish').val();
var colleagueVal = jQuery('#colleague').val();
var taskVal = jQuery('#task').val();
var sendData = {
        "email": emailVal,
        "password": passwordVal,
        "first_name": first_nameVal,
        "last_name": last_nameVal,
        "gender": genderVal,
        "dateofbirth": dateofbirthVal,
        "phone_number": phone_numberVal,
        "address": addressVal,
        "city": cityVal,
        "zipcode": zipcodeVal,
        "country": countryVal,
        "nationality": nationalityVal,
        "speak_danish": speak_danishVal,
        "colleague": colleagueVal,
        "task": taskVal
};
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: URL + 'user/add_user',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(sendData),
    success: function(data, status, response) {
        console.log('Success');
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(sendData);
    }
}); 
}
```

Like i said i know my controller and model is working, since it works in POSTMAN, but none the less let me know if i should share that also, 
for you to be able to help better? :)

Btw plz bear with me, since my this is my very first posting on stack overflow ever, and i also am fairly new to coding in genral.

Thank you in advance awesome community! :)

Comment: How are you calling your `register` function? Do you have an event listener setup? If you are not seeing a POST request in the network tab then your jQuery.ajax call isn't being made at all, look to see if you have any errors in the console. Also you have `contentType: 'application/json',` PHP natively does not understand JSON request body content, so your data will not be put into the super globals like `$_POST`.

Comment: Yea i am sorry here is all my event listeners
    ` jQuery('#main').on('click', '.link-login-submit', login);
      jQuery('#main').on('click', '.signup', registrationPage);`

     this is the one :)  `jQuery('#main').on('click', 'link-register-user', register);`

Comment: Offtopic, adding stings like that is not truly the fastest way. Even done client-side, its tales unnecessary cpu power. In your production version maken i would make it one string..

Comment: if you used `'link-register-user'` that is why it isn't being called, it would need to be `'.link-register-user'`, note the dot in front, that is the class selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is how you are doing your `.ajax()` options. Let's change it up a little.

Since you are using event delegation, get the element that contains your inputs i.e. `#main` by using [`e.delegateTarget`](https://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/). Then use a nice method called [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to serialize all your form inputs. (You may have to rename some of your input `name` attributes to pass the key-value pairs in the correct format that you are handling them on the server-side.)

I am not too sure about `contentType` option as I've never used it for anything, so I'd also remove that. Based on Patrick's comment, it would give an undesired behavior.

So, the code would simply look like

```
function register(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: URL + 'user/add_user',
        type: 'POST',
        data: jQuery(e.delegateTarget).find(':input').serialize(),
        success: function (data, status, response) {
            console.log('Success');
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(sendData);
        }
    }); 
}

// somewhere
jQuery('#main').on('click', 'link-register-user', register);
```